# How to scrape the full html code from "developer tools" in Chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape many parts of many websites, with for loop.

I tried BeautifulSoup and Selenium, but it didn't return all the html part that I want. Actually, the result that I got from

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
```

,or other parsers, is not the same as the full html code I saw in "Developer tools" in Chrome

So I'm trying to scrape the code from "Developer tools" instead, likes copying the full html code in "Developer tools" after entering the website.

How can I do that? It would be appreciated if you could give some code for example.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is common that websites will use javascript to manipulate the DOM and add elements. Beautifulsoup does not account for this, it does not execute javascript. It simply helps you extract data from static files that contain html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium should show exactly the same data

If the website dynamically changes over time due to various Javascript functions, then there's nothing you can really do except periodically make new requests to capture snapshots of that state.

BeautifulSoup does not load Javascript

Comment: Thank you very much, you made my day. I carefully checked Selenium again and it worked : )